# How to get data of current week Start on Saturday end in Friday from SQL server

Tags: sql-server, select

how can I get the data from sql server for current week starting in Saturday ending in Friday, so select all data from Saturday to Friday for the current week.

I found this code but started in Sunday and I can't change it:

```
where Date >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) AND Date <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [SET DATEFIRST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on MS Docs.

> Sets the first day of the week to a number from 1 through 7.

Where:

```
1   Monday
2   Tuesday
3   Wednesday
4   Thursday
5   Friday
6   Saturday
7   Sunday (default, U.S. English)
```

Have a look at next example:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME;
SET @CurrentDate = CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-01-18');

SET DATEFIRST 1
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate);
RETURNS '2017-01-16' (Monday)

SET DATEFIRST 2
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate);
RETURNS '2017-01-17' (Tuesday)

SET DATEFIRST 3
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate);
RETURNS '2017-01-18' (Wednesday)

SET DATEFIRST 4
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate);
RETURNS '2017-01-12' (Thursday)

SET DATEFIRST 5
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate);
RETURNS '2017-01-13' (Friday)

SET DATEFIRST 6
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate);
RETURNS '2017-01-14' (Saturday)

SET DATEFIRST 7
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate);
RETURNS '2017-01-15' (Monday)
```

You can check it here: http://rextester.com/YSGVM53271

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, actually it should from number 0 to 7,
edit your answer to make it the answer.

Comment: are you sure it runs 0-7?  That would suggest 8 different settings - what does 0 do?  Maybe it does something - but in any case, you would not need it since the answer covers all days.

Comment: if i put it form 1 the first Saturday not shown, please if you can try it try it and told me

Comment: @Cato it uses -8 I suppouse because he uses < date_fin, -7 requires <=

Comment: @Rabeeaqabaha, what do you mean? If you  `SET DATEFIRST 1` then first day of week is Monday. In the current example it returns 'Monday 16-01-2017',

Comment: What i want is showing data from Saturday to Friday, so if i make it 1-7 its showing from Saturday to Saturday i don't know why, but if i make it from 0 to 7 its showing what i want , but I'm afraid  that I'm wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

By default the week will start from `sunday`. To change it use [**`DATEFIRST`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx).

```
SET DATEFIRST 6

WHERE  Date >= Cast(Dateadd(dd, -Datepart(WEEKDAY, Getdate()) + 1, Getdate()) AS DATE)
       AND Date < Cast(Dateadd(dd, 7 - Datepart(WEEKDAY, Getdate()) + 1, Getdate()) AS DATE)
```

More info on `DATEFIRST`

```
+---------------------------+--------------------------+
|           Value           | First day of the week is |
+---------------------------+--------------------------+
| 1                         | Monday                   |
| 2                         | Tuesday                  |
| 3                         | Wednesday                |
| 4                         | Thursday                 |
| 5                         | Friday                   |
| 6                         | Saturday                 |
| 7 (default, U.S. English) | Sunday                   |
+---------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.  It works regardless of the `SET DATEFIRST` value:

```
where [Date] >= CAST(DATEADD(d, -(@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())) % 7, @d) as DATE)
  and [Date] < CAST(DATEADD(d, -(@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())) % 7 + 6, @d) as DATE)
```

Comment: what is the column name @d ??

Answer (score 0):

try this example

```
SELECT count(AddTime) AS time,
   CASE
       WHEN (weekday(AddTime)<=3) THEN date(AddTime + INTERVAL (3-weekday(AddTime)) DAY)
       ELSE date(AddTime + INTERVAL (3+7-weekday(AddTime)) DAY)
   END AS week_days
FROM SAAS_Appoint
WHERE Status = 2
AND AddTime > "2020-01-01 00:00:00"
GROUP BY week_days;
```

$weekArr = array( 'Monday' => 0, 'Tuesday' => 1, 'Wednesday' => 2, 'Thursday' => 3, 'Friday' => 4, 'Saturday' => 5, 'Sunday' => 6);

the example is start from friday and end at thusrday。
just replace 3 to any day you like。