# How to get data of current week Start on Saturday end in Friday from SQL Server with current day

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, select

I want get weekly report, how can I get the data from SQL Server database for current week starting in Saturday ending in Friday, I try this query but I have to update daily and I don't want this method.

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE )) [Week_Start_Date]
```

Comment: Found the same Question already on here :) Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724268/how-to-get-data-of-current-week-start-on-saturday-end-in-friday-from-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

DECLARE @WeekStartDay INT, @WeekEndDay INT

SELECT @WeekStartDay = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), @WeekEndDay = 6 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())

SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, -@WeekStartDay, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE )) [Week_Start_Date],
DATEADD(DAY, @WeekEndDay, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE )) [Week_End_Date]